# App crash at boot because API Key for google map is not found

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-manifest

everyone! I have a problem where my app just crashes at boot because it can't find my API key, it seems... What I'm trying to achieve is to add a map fragment to my activity, but it will not find my API key. I just wonder if some of you have had this issue and can spot the error I'm making, because I can't?

I have provided the error message I get, my AndroidManifest.xml and the method where I try to switch to the map fragment.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{no.premer.mytravels/no.premer.mytravels.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2407)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fk.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzvu(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1766)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:917)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2407)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!--
The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And Here is where I add the code for the map.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().compassEnabled(true).zoomControlsEnabled(true).mapToolbarEnabled(true));
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // call getMapAsync() to set OnMapReadyCallback on map fragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mapFragment, "map").commit();

    mTitle = "Some Title";
    restoreActionBar();
}
```

Comment: Try putting the actual API KEY into your manifest rather than a reference to a value in your strings.xml.

Comment: It actually worked... Thanks man, it was sloppy of me to not even try it!

Comment: The wierd thing was that it actually showed the key when I just had the reference to it...

Comment: There may be something about how that particular value is evaluated, and it is not making it to the API correctly when it is a reference like that. I don't know for sure though.

Comment: I tried making the google_maps_api.xml again just to check if it worked, because I think it is better with the reference to it, and that worked... I had previously just copied the file from one of my other repositories and that's probably why it didn't find it somehow.